# Cellphone Wifi hotspot<->Windows 10 Enterprise<->Dlink DIR 822<->devices

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I want to set this up:
Cellphone Wifi hotspot<->Windows 10<->Dlink DIR-822<->users & devices. I have the cellphone<->W10 connection working, tested by having users connect to either W10 & hotspot.

update.

I'm finding that Android is somewhat unstable as a hotspot. It's not unprecedented, Android is notorious for stalling updates (there's a 10 step procedure when it's really gummed up). I've only been running Android for a couple of months, I had expected them to be farther along by now.  W10 is doing annoying things with repeated connects, such as creating a new instance for each hotspot reconnect in Control Panel\Network Internet\Network Connections. Reconnecting to clear Android sludge gets that going. W10 also doesn't play well with bridging the hotspot to the 882 (cabled) ethernet port. IP access on W10 internet disappears when you bridge. I'm not out of gas just yet, there may be some things to do with w10 sharing the hotspot back to the local devices.

Update: I have it working. hotspot->w10(usb wifi 1)->w10(usb wifi share)->router->wireless client. The client connects to the router, not w10 usb ethernet.

I have enough cellphone bandwidth for my purposes and budget. The next step up would be microwave (75M/sec, unlimited, $80/mo) but that also would involve a relay from the neighbor - I'm in TN and wireless is the only option. Some areas a few miles away are pulling fibre, so there's a glimmer of long term hope.

Comment: What have you tried? How are devices configured? Where are you stuck?

Comment: You need a router that can accept cellular as its source of Internet to distribute to users.  Otherwise, the wireless hotspot needs to deliver signal to more than one user independently. Most cellular hotspots can provide signal to multiple users but bandwidth may be an issue.